# Accepting an untrusted security certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates

What is the risk of accepting an untrusted site security certificate in your browser if you're not entering any data, but merely browsing the site?

Comment: If you're authenticated, an attacker can easily steal your session cookie and capture your session. Or they can use Javascript to perform actions on your behalf.

Comment: As he said, you won't be entering any data

Comment: @Lucas: is this in reply to Stephen's comment? If so, "not entering any data" does not prevent a spoofed site from carrying out a MITM attack against the real site (session hijacking, capturing credentials including 'remember me') and using the browser as an anonymous proxy for other nefarious activities

Comment: If you weren't browsing securely, how would you know that what you're seeing is what you're requesting from the site?

Comment: Just to clarify, I was NOT logged in to the site. Just browsing a Joe Public. But I see now about possible false information, malicious downloads, etc.

Answer (score 2):

X.509 security certificates are mainly about the authentication of the site providing it, i.e. you know the site is really the site it claims to be. This is why e.g. banks use certificates at a high trust level (which means they are signed by more certification authorities, signed by more established cas rather than unknown ones, etc.).
Even without providing any data, with untrusted certificates, you have the risk of becoming a victim of a man-in-the-middle attack or phishing, where someone tries to either modify or spoof the site you're visting. This way, you might get false information, which can do in certain cases as much harm as stealing your credentials.